# Passing array elements in javascript as parameters for an AJAX POST request

Tags: php, javascript, prototypejs

I've taken some input values from the user and I want to post these values as arguments in my AJAX request so I can add an entry to a database in PHP:

My function in JS is:

```
function reqAdd()
{
    var tablename = $("table").options[$("table").selectedIndex].value
    var fields = new Array();
    var inputs = $$("input.postfields");
    new Ajax.Request(
            "process.php?type=add&table="+tablename,
            {
                method: "post",
                parameters:
                onSuccess: functionName,
                onFailure: ajaxFailure
            }
    );
}
```

The variable inputs contains all the input fields I need so I just need to extract their values but how can I place them into the parameters section if they have no key? they are just values.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use Form.serialize() http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Form/serialize/

Comment: Why don't they have a key? In what format does your PHP expect them? You can always use a custom serialisation for them, like CSV or JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Form.serializeElements()` which takes an array of elements, `$$("input.postfields")` and turns it into a querystring or object ready for POSTing.

So

```
var inputs = $$("input.postfields");
inputs = Form.serializeElements(inputs); //add this line
```

And

```
parameters: inputs,
```

Personally I like passing objects to my Ajax requests, and skipping the submit inputs so I would pass an options object to `serializeElements()`

```
inputs = Form.serializeElements(inputs,{hash:true,submit:false});
```

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/serializeElements/